# Laravel Eloquent Relationship: How to get parent of parent information from child using Laravel eloquent model relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, rest

I am facing a problem getting a query result in Laravel Controller.
Let me describe to you..

I have three models in Laravel Project ModelA, ModelB, ModelC.

### The tables look like this:

1. Table for ModelA:

| a_id | name | info |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | name1 | info1 |
| 2 | name2 | info2 |

2. Table for ModelB:

| b_id | col1 | a_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | value1 | 1 |
| 2 | value2 | 1 |

3. Table for ModelC:

| c_id | col1 | b_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | val_1 | 1 |
| 2 | val_2 | 1 |

**Relations:**
ModelC to ModelB -> Many to One 
ModelB to ModelA -> Many to One 

I want to return ModelC information with related ModelA and ModelB data that means, I want to get Data like:

```
data = [ 
    {
        c_id: 1,
        col1: val_1,
        b_id: 1,
        bdata: {
           b_id: 1,
           col1: value1,
           a_id: 1,
           adata: {
             a_id: 1,
             name: name1,
             info: info1,
           } 
        }
     },
     {
        c_id: 2,
        col1: val_2,
        b_id: 1,
        bdata: {
           b_id: 1,
           col1: value1,
           a_id: 1,
           adata: {
             a_id: 1,
             name: name1,
             info: info1,
           } 
        }
      }
    ]
```

How to define relationships in modelA, modelC, and ModelB ? 
And how to write the query in modelC Controller to get the data like this?

Thank you, In advance...

Comment: This is well documented, so at least give it a try... https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships for use in api look at the "with()" method.

Comment: @GertB.Thank you.

Comment: @GertB., I can handle it when it's about two models. but this time, it needs to get parent of parent information...

Comment: That is basically the same. if you use the 'with' method you can do with('parent_relation.parent_parent_relation'). (using the names of the relation offcourse)

Comment: already Solved. Thank you for your time....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **Problem solved**

### My Solution:

My code in ModelC Controller:

```
$data = ModelC::with('modelB')->get();
```

Relation function in ModelB:

```
public function modelA(){
    return $this->belongsTo(ModelA::class);
}
```

Relation function in ModelC:

```
public function modelB(){
    return $this->belongsTo(ModelB::class)->with('modelA');
}
```